# Android Jelly Bean build problems - libwebcore.so

Tags: android, android-source, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've been trying to build 4.2.1 on an Ubuntu 10.04 system

```
lunch full-eng
make -j12
```

but I keep running into issues.  They seemed to stem from libwebcore so I tried:

```
make clean
make -j12 libwebcore showcommands
```

This also fails.  The output (not entirely everything, stuff towards the end) is at this link:

http://pastie.org/6076543

Sorry if this is messy/not useful, I really don't know what's going on.   This system has a 6-core Ivy Bridge CPU and 63GB of RAM so it should certainly not be a resource issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of references to 'x86' libraries in that log. Android 4.2.1 requires a x86-64 OS & libraries to build.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 10.04 x64...when you say "OS & libraries" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Hmmm. Usually if it is a 64bit os & setup, it will specifically reference 64 when mentioning x86. Just to be sure, run "uname -a" and make sure the output is similar to "Linux 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP ... x86_64 GNU/Linux". I am using Ubuntu 10.04/64 to build Jelly Bean and I don't have any issues.

Comment: It's definitely 64 bit.  I get "Linux 2.6.32-45-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP ... x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: I'm running out of ideas for you.. you did all the apt-get pre requisites? I've used the same version of Ubuntu on two separate boxes to build JellyBean by following source.android.com's instructions.